# Pymongo how to sync secondary with primary

Tags: python, database, mongodb, synchronization, pymongo

I know I can go to mongo and then follow:

```
mongo --host <host>:<port>
rs.slaveOk()
rs.syncFrom("<host>:<port>")
```

Is there any way to do it in python with pymongo?

Comment: The [`replSetSetSyncFrom` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetSyncFrom/#dbcmd.replSetSyncFrom) provides a temporary override of default behaviour. What is your use case for setting this programatically? It's fine to do so, but this may not do what you expect depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rs.syncFrom` wraps the [replSetSyncFrom command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetSyncFrom/#dbcmd.replSetSyncFrom) so you can call it from Pymongo like:

```
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27018')
res = conn.admin.command('replSetSyncFrom', 'localhost:27019')
```

Executing this:

```
{'syncFromRequested': 'localhost:27019', 'prevSyncTarget': 'localhost:27017', 'ok': 1.0, ...
```

Comment: Hey, Kevin thanks for the answer. Is there a way to sync it permanently rather than just temporary for a run??